# Is it possible to add clause "must" above existing one

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql

I have a query like that, and I would like to add new "must" clause above this existing one.

```
   {
     "query" : {
        "bool" : {
          "must": [...],
          "should": [...],
          "adjust_pure_negative": true,
          "boost": 10
      }
     }
    }
```

Expected query. What I would like to achieve is must array, and inside of him the second must with should. It is possible ?

```
{
 "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must":[{
      "must": [...],
      "should": [...],
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 10
  ]}
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: How does java tag relate to this question?

Comment: Ups. You are right. I have to implement this query into java . But the question relate just to elasticSearch.